# Angular2 cannot get mock data from Service

Tags: angular

UPDATE: sorry i copied the wrong version of my code: i did call `then` inside the service as shown now.

I'm creating a Service that provides mock data (following a similar structure as [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)) but cannot get data for some reason.

snippet from AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getData();
  }


  constructor(private _dataService: DataService){ }

  getData(){
      console.log('get data called');
      var data = this._dataService.getData();
      console.log('data type is '+typeof(data));
      console.log('data key is ');
      for(var k in data){
        console.log(k);
      }
```

DataService is as follows:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {MOCK_DATA} from './mock-data';

@Injectable()
export class DataService{
  getData(){
    return Promise.resolve(MOCK_DATA).then(data => data);
  }
}
```

mock data is:

```
export var MOCK_DATA = {
  "apple": [
    {"taste": "apple", "really": false},
    {"taste": "random", "really": true},
  ],
  "orange": [
    {"taste": "orange", "really": false},
    {"taste": "random", "really": true},
  ],
}
```

however the console.log results are:

```
get data called
app.component.ts:46 data type object
app.component.ts:47 data key 
app.component.ts:49 __zone_symbol__state
app.component.ts:49 __zone_symbol__value
app.component.ts:49 then
app.component.ts:49 catch
```

Comment: I think you need to import `RBACService` into your `AppComponent` and inject in its constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `then` method on the returned promise by the `getData` method to be able to receive the data:

```
getData() {
  console.log('get data called');
  this._dataService.getData().then(data => {
    // Handle the data

    // For example
    console.log('data type is '+typeof(data));
    console.log('data key is ');
    for(var k in data){
      console.log(k);
    }
  });
}
```

The `then` method must be used within the component and not in the service.

Your service should be:

```
@Injectable()
export class RBACService{
  getData(){
    return Promise.resolve(MOCK_DATA);
  }
}
```

instead of

```
@Injectable()
export class RBACService{
  getData(){
    return Promise.resolve(MOCK_DATA).then(data => data);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `then` method must be used outside the service ;-) In your case it's within the service...

Comment: is there anyway to use `then` inside Service so that it returns the actual data instead of a promise? I heard that it's good to return data instead of promise inside service because the caller doesn't need to know how the data is passed (say we might change to Observable in the future). thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! If you retrieve your data synchronously, you don't need promise / observable and you can return data directly. That said, in most cases, it's from HTTP requests so it's asynchronous and you need either.

Comment: yes, in the asynchronous case, is it ever possible to use `then` inside the service? thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use a `then` method in the service if you want to implement promise chaining. You can return in the `then` callback either a raw value or another promise. But in any case, the corresponding result will be received within a callback specified using another `then` method and outside the service...

Comment: Hi @ThierryTemplier! I'm sorry, but I found your answer because I have the same error for another one problem. I ask you to see my question, because maybe you can help me.stackoverflow.com/questions/40141597/….

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some important part of your code in the decorator for the `AppComponent`, something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { RBACService } from './(serviceName).service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `whatever...`,
    providers: [RBACService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
```

Where `(serviceName)` should be the file name of your inyectable service and **whatch out cause you inyected it at the constructor** as `DataService` and it's actually called `RBACService`...

Comment: thanks for the reply. sorry about the name mismatch; i changed them in SO question to make it more generic, so it wasn't actually the cause of the problem.